# Force Google login page to appear when accessing a Google Form?

Tags: google-forms

I'm trying to create a Google Form that is locked to a specific Google Apps domain, however I'm running into the issue where if I send out the link to the form to my users and they are logged in to their personal email, they are sent to a page that says: "You need permission to view this form" with no link to log into their domain email.

Thus, I was wondering if there was any way I could force a Google log-in page to appear for my domain when I share the Google Forms link. I've tried hosting the form in an iFrame with sandboxing, but Google still remembers the login and still redirects to the "You need permission" page.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask].

Answer (score 4):

Take your form's url and prepend it with:

```
https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?continue=
```

For example, if your form's url were:

```
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIZQLSfuP8rG64zNLv8YC35pPZo7cfXuzoJJXs3ZlNpnhGcbRN6jZQ/viewform
```

you should change it to:

```
https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?continue=https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIZQLSfuP8rG64zNLv8YC35pPZo7cfXuzoJJXs3ZlNpnhGcbRN6jZQ/viewform
```

Answer (score 2):

A workaround is to embed the form into a site in Google Sites shared only with people on the domain.

Those users that go to the site while signed in with an unauthorized account, will see something similar to the following screenshot:

[image: You need permission - Google Sites]

Comment: Is there any way to edit what that page says? For example, changing "You need permission" to "Please sign in with your company email."